# how to add multiple maps into different pages of a rails application using gmaps4rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

i tried multiple ways of trying to get the maps to show on my home's index.html.erb and locations's index.html.erb but noting seems to be working correctly. My overall goal is to be able to edit content in my locations page but only show the content without editing anything on the home page. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

my current home `index.html.erb` (Note: i am only showing the javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(handler) {
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: { id: 'map' } }, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
  });
</script>
```

my locations `index.html.erb`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(handler) {
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: { id: 'map' } }, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
  });
</script>
```

and also for both controller i have this in my `index` method:

```
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|
        marker.lat location.latitude
        marker.lng location.longitude
        marker.infowindow location.summary
       marker.json({title: location.title })
       end
  end
```

and by the way i have a model `location` which provides the lat,long,summary,title.

Comment: What are your issues? Any error? Code works see: http://apneadiving.github.io/ so you have to give more info here. I suspect you have nil coordinates

Comment: the maps worked perfectly when i only had the locations controller but then i added a home controller and tried to make a second map in there but first of all it no longer stores the location it just stores blank spaces (While listing newly added locations it just lists blank spaces) and also the map just does not show in the home page.

Comment: Any js error? Its impossible to guess what is wrong here

Comment: no js error. it might be the nil coordinates which you mentioned earlier because it stores blank spaces to the database when i add a new location. i use the same variables in both my home and locations controllers. i tried to change the internal: { id: 'map' } to be different in both classes but it still does not show the map in the home page and also cant add a location either.

Comment: If you put `map` it should match an id in your dom. Otherwise you have a css issue

Answer (score 0):

gmaps4rails does not go good with certain gems i had to remove a few to stop storing empty strings. And after that i also changed the handler in my home view to handler2 to make it work. thank you